# write a cinnamon applet that spawns a command

Tags: javascript, applet, command, output, cinnamon

I'm writing an applet for Cinnamon GTK (Javascript).

After many hours of research and trial and error, I finally managed to spawn a command.  But I don't think that it's working efficiently. Many pages return 404 and some pages talk about the food spice and some pages talk about applets with other languages...

Anyhow, what I'm saying is that documentation is scare.

Using `Util` (from `/usr/share/cinnamon/js/util.js`), trying:

```
Util.spawn_async(['/bin/bash', '-c', comm], CommandOutput);
```

and I can get the output with my 'CommandOutput(result)' function.
Now I've got another method using:

```
let [res, pid, in_fd, out_fd, err_fd] = GLib.spawn_async_with_pipes(null, ["/usr/bin/command-name", "command-args"], null, GLib.SpawnFlags.SEARCH_PATH, null);
out_reader = new Gio.DataInputStream({base_stream: new Gio.UnixInputStream({fd: out_fd})});
let [out, size] = out_reader.read_line(null);
```

And this seems to work...

**Please tell me the best way to perform string-functions on a command's output?**

**Is there some reference manual?**  What is the best search phrase (in Google, etc)?

P.S.  I'd also like to write the command's output to a temp file.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some resources for writing applets:

- [Writing applets](http://developer.linuxmint.com/reference/git/cinnamon-tutorials/write-applet.html)
- [Cinnamon wiki](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/wiki)
- [General coding tips](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/wiki/General-coding-tips)

However, IMHO your best bet for applet development is to go to the [cinnamon-spices-applets](https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-spices-applets) github repository and do a search for examples of what you are trying to accomplish.